# How to create Alerts for changes to users personal details

Tags: alert, user-profile-property

From time to time peoples personal details change, for instance:
phone number
job title
manager
even their name!

How can I create an alert on changes such as these?
In particular I'd like to be alerted when a new member joins the team (by which I mean same manager).

Comment: OOTB you get a list of notification settings [image] (http://habaneroconsulting.com/~/media/hab/blogimages/9c9b1480-2b0d-4dfc-be68-423697b938c7.ashx?la=en&hash=64BA6E2B3F7FDF7E796453D5D54051EF9BBDFC3C). You will get Newsfeed notification for the people you are following.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each user can edit their Newsfeed settings ([MSDN ref](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Change-your-newsfeed-settings-dbb4db06-37c2-4e75-bc08-1ecf144fbd8d?rs=en-US&ui=en-US&ad=US)). To change your newsfeed settings:

1. Click your name at the top of a SharePoint or Office 365 site in your organization, and then click About Me.
2. Click edit your profile to display the Edit Details page.
3. Click the ellipsis (…), and then clickNewsfeed Settings.
4. Edit yourFollowed #Tags, Email Notifications,People I follow, and Activities I want to share in my newsfeed information as needed.
5. Click Save all and close.

Let's say Craig is promoted to Manager (title field update), depends on his settings, the people following Craig will see the news at his Newsfeed. When someone tag your name you will get notification email. Of course, you also get Newsfeed notification for the people you are following.

However, to do what exactly your need (new member joins team) is not easy. There is no OOTB function. You will need to write some code to monitor all User Profile update for "manager" field and then check against everyone's manager.

As a simple workaround (at least it works in my company), you can setup team site for each team. Enable the Newsfeed for each team site and have all team members following their own team site. In this way, all team members will see the Team Newsfeed in their MySite Newsfeed page. They can post Newsfeed directly towards Team Newsfeed, too.

When a new member join, add him or her into the team site. Then have the team leader say some welcome message in the Team Newsfeed. Every team members will aware the new comer. I think it is far much better then email alert.

Comment: Thanks for your answer @Mark. I had not found the Edit Details page, it's hidden away in my organisation but I managed to reach it by clicking on 'Change my Photo'.Having reached the Newsfeed Settings page all the checkboxes are off by default, so it seems that I can't be notified of anything unless the other user has changed their settings?

Comment: I like your suggestion using the Team Newsfeed and I think this would work (from a technical point of view). I my case the problem is that team leaders can't be relied upon to make the announcement.

Comment: By OOTB default those check boxes are all checked. It seems the SharePoint team have them all off by some reason (privacy?). Yes you will not get any notification unless your followed users have checked those boxes.